# Linq to SQL to map a nullable bool value to IsNull and not = NULL

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, nullable

I'm trying to use Linq to SQL to filter a table with a nullable bool value based on a variable.

But if the variable's value is NULL, LINQ seems to translate the query to `Field = NULL` instead of `Field IS NULL`.

Based on other posts I've seen to use `object.Equals` to map correctly.  And that works, but only when the variable's value is null.

Sample code:

```
    bool? relevantValue = null;
    var q = from m in MyTable
             where ???
             select m;
```

**Case 1:**

If where clause is `object.Equals(m.IsRelevant, relevantValue)`, it works when `relevantValue` is null and true, but returns incorrect results when `relevantValue` = false.
It translates in SQL to

> WHERE (
>       (CASE 
>           WHEN [t0].[IsRelevant] = 1 THEN 1
>           ELSE 0
>        END)) = 0

**Case 2:**
For `where (relevantValue == null ? object.Equals(m.IsRelevant, relevantValue) : m.IsRelevant == relevantValue)` it works for `relevantValue` = true or false, but when null gives an error that:

> The argument 'value' was the wrong type. Expected 'System.Boolean'. Actual 'System.Nullable`1[System.Boolean]'.

Do I have other options that will work for null, true and false?

Comment: Instead of null try : DBNull.Value or relevantValue.Count() > 0

Comment: Good suggestion.  But depending on where and how I use it, I either get "Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.DBNull' to 'bool?" or "Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'bool?' and 'DBNull'".  As relevantValue is a bool? the .Count() suggestion does not work either.

Comment: Is the type of column also bool? in your database definition ? You show only a local variable to us.

Comment: When you have null you have to cast to (object) .  You have [bool?].  So you need : (object)relevantValue == DBNull.Value

Comment: @Holger: Yes, it is. It's created as: [IsRelevant] [bit] NULL

Comment: @jdweng: I've changed my where clause to:  where ((object)relevantValue == DBNull.Value ? object.Equals(m.IsRelevant, relevantValue) : m.IsRelevant == relevantValue).  Works for true and false, but when null it gives a runtime error that: The argument 'value' was the wrong type. Expected 'System.Boolean'. Actual 'System.Nullable`1[System.Boolean]'.

Comment: What are you using to connect to the Database ? Is this Entity Framework ? What type is 'MyTable' ? It's not important what you define in your database, the datatype you are loading, must match.How is your m defined ?

Comment: MyTable is a standard table in SQL Server. Contains a couple of columns but IsRelevant is scripted out as [IsRelevant] [bit] NULL.  No default values.  My dbContext was created with sqlmetal.

Comment: Do you still have : bool? relevantValue = null;  Change [bool?] to [bool].

Comment: But I need to be able to assign null values to that var in order to filter for the nulls. For now, I've split the query up in 2 parts with a normal if (null) { xx } else { xx }. It works like that, but would be nice to still know the short hand solution.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I missed something about the question but, Why not use the Nullable<> .HasValue and .Value to get a real boolean?

```
IQueryable<Person> People = new List<Person>
{
    new Person
    {
        PersonId = 1,
        IsMarried = true
    },
    new Person
    {
        PersonId = 2,
        IsMarried = false
    },
}
.AsQueryable();

bool? isMarried = null;
var query = from p in People
            where !isMarried.HasValue || (isMarried.HasValue && p.IsMarried == isMarried.Value)
            select p;
```

Comment: Thank you. Your suggestion works where (in my case) isRelevant = true or false. But when null, I get an error that "Nullable object must have a value".  I've played around with casting in this sample, but not working (yet).

Comment: So you have null value in the table and you want to get them when the variable is null?


where (!isMarried.HasValue && !p.IsMarried.HasValue) || (isMarried.HasValue && p.IsMarried == isMarried.Value)

This works for me, weird, let me know :)

Comment: My complete clause is:  (!relevantValue.HasValue && !m.IsRelevant.HasValue) || (relevantValue.HasValue && m.IsRelevant == relevantValue.Value).  
That gives the runtime error that "Nullable object must have a value." when relevantValue = null.

Comment: Wow that's so weird, let me see if I can reproduce